# What's wrong with this line?

Tags: string, vb6

I am trying to remove all the " from a string called s1, I have this line

```
s1=replace (s1, """, "")
```

But I get a compile error saying it is expecting a list separator or )

How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even the syntax highlighting in the question shows what's wrong.

Comment: @Tadeusz A. Kadłubowski: But syntax highlighting on Stack Overflow doesn’t work for VB.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? That’s a completely valid, clearly-worded question with a very non-obvious answer.

Answer (score 7):

Your second string isn’t properly delimited. If you want to use a quotation mark (`"`) inside your string, you need to *double* it. Since your string *only* consists of a quotation mark, it looks as follows:

- Quotation mark to start the string, `"`.
- Double quotation mark that represents a single quotation mark inside the string, `""`.
- Ending quotation mark, `"`.

In summary:

```
s1 = Replace(s1, """", "")
```

Answer (score 4):

Konrad's suggestion is the one you should go with, but here's another for completeness/amusement.

```
s1 = Replace(s1, Chr(34), "")
```

And if you ever get bored at a party and need something to read on your phone, here's the list of the 256 such ASCII codes you can use with Chr().

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z4t9ed1%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Did you really write `"""`? You have to escape the `"` in the middle - just double it like:

```
replace( s1, """", "" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Commonly used syntaxes are:

```
s1=replace (s1, "\"", "")
s1=replace (s1, """", "")
s1=replace (s1, '"', "")
```

Comment: Yeah, but it's good to know all possible notations just in case.. It's not like our brain would overflow with information :)